# formatting data caption in light box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox

how to format the data caption
I am planning to display three different names for a single  image 
after i click the cube light box opens and the caption comes with div tag
but i wanted to display it one by one on the light box

its working fine without light box

```
$data = '';
$('[data-caption]').each(function(){
    $data += '<div>' + $(this).data('caption') + '</div>';
});
$('body').append('<div id="more-info">' + $data + '</div>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrpLT/52/

```
 <body>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span10">
                    <div class="melonhtml5_gallery">
                        <div data-caption="<div>Paul Scholes</div> <div>Wayne Rooney</div> <div>Sir Alex Ferguson</div>" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/inventory.png"></div>

                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: You can't unless you have the ability to change `Gallery` to use `.html` to append the caption (`.addClass('captio').html(g ? g : ""),`

Comment: @ExplosionPills thanks for your reply...can you update it in the fiddle...i am not sure how to change it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrpLT/63/

This requires updating the `Gallery` class to use `.html` instead of `.text` when the caption is appended specifically in the `onClick` function on the line:

```
var m = $("<div>").addClass("caption").html(g ? g : ""),
```

As long as you are able to do that, you can get this to work for you.

Comment: thanks for your reply....but i wanted the three different names to be displayed for the same image....